# Installing Docker.io on Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: azure, ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-14.04

I'm running a virtual machine in Windows Azure with the prebuild image for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

When I want to install `Docker.io` like described here:
http://blog.docker.io/2014/04/docker-in-ubuntu-ubuntu-in-docker/

The installation works but when i`m running:

```
sudo docker.io pull ubuntu
```

An error will be thrown:

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is `docker -d` running on this host?

Can anyone help or has the similar problem?

P.S.: Can anyone with a high reputation create a Tag for Ubuntu-14.04?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Evidently the docker daemon is not running. You wanna check /etc/default/docker.conf for proper configuration and issue

```
sudo service docker.io start
```

or

```
sudo service docker start
```

depending on how they called the service

Comment: Thanks service is up and running but now I get the next error: `dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied`

Comment: OK I think that is not config related or so!! https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/5314

Comment: OK `usermod -a -G docker {{your_user}}` fixed it for now

Comment: service docker restart worked for me instead of start.

Answer (score 6):

Adding myself to the docker group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker myuser
```

and rebooting the machine worked for me. This solution is discussed in: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/5314

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu 14.04, the `docker.io` package installs Docker 0.9.1.

According to the [documentation](http://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/), to install the current version use these commands:

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 36A1D7869245C8950F966E92D8576A8BA88D21E9
$ sudo sh -c "echo deb https://get.docker.io/ubuntu docker main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list"
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install lxc-docker
```

There is also a simple script available to help with this process:

```
$ curl -s https://get.docker.io/ubuntu/ | sudo sh
```

Alternatively, check the [azure-docker-registry](https://github.com/fernandoacorreia/azure-docker-registry) project for an example of how to automate Azure provisioning and Docker container deployment. For instance, this [Ansible playbook](https://github.com/fernandoacorreia/azure-docker-registry/blob/master/tools/ansible/roles/docker-registry/tasks/docker.yml):

```
- name: create docker data directory
  file: path=/mnt/data/docker state=directory

- name: store docker files in data disk
  file: src=/mnt/data/docker dest=/var/lib/docker state=link

- name: add repository key
  command: creates=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 36A1D7869245C8950F966E92D8576A8BA88D21E9

- name: copy repository source file
  copy: src=docker.list dest=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list

- name: install docker package
  apt: name=lxc-docker update_cache=yes state=present
```

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure to symlink the `docker.io` binary to `docker` to use the tutorials/documentation without rewriting every command.

```
ln -s /usr/bin/docker.io /usr/bin/docker
```

Answer (score 1):

Run `docker -d` to see if it shows any error messages.

If apparmor is missing install it with `sudo apt-get install apparmor`

Then `sudo service docker start`

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say but sometime official docker installation procedure fails on Ubuntu 14.04.
One can simply install docker using below given commands *[Quick and Dirty]*

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install docker.io
```